# Is it possible to reuse the security tristate control field?

Tags: sitecore-client

Is it possible to reuse the tristate from the security manager i.e.
[image: Secuirty Tristate]

I can see "Developer Types -> Tristate" in the select list, but it's just a select list itself, not the nicer security one.

[image: Default tristate]

Comment: Yes. No. Maybe.

Comment: @jammykam I was very tempted to add a comment that was just `default` :D. Having said that I don't think there's an easy way to accomplish this using things that already exist. You'll most likely need to create a custom field that inherits the logic of the tristate but has a custom html template. Create a class that inherits from the class the tristate field points to. Then copy the tristate field item to a folder for custom fields (create one if it doesn't exist). Update the field for assembly and class to point to your custom class. Override the Render method in your custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it really isn't possible. That "tristate" doesn't even remotely resemble a content editor field. The logic for the security editor is in the `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.ItemSecurityEditor.ItemSecurityEditorPage` in the `Sitecore.Client` assembly. Various methods in that class build the HTML that is output to the page after you add a user or role to the list that you want to assign security to. An individual selector is rendered by the `RenderSelector` method. Unfortunately it is writing HTML directly to  an `HtmlTextWriter`.

You could build a custom field that mimics this selector and uses the same images and styling, but you would need to essentially build it from scratch.